# LiveAgent Chat with External ID

Tags: javascript, liveagent

I am integrating a third-party site with Salesforce LiveAgent to include passing in an external ID for a Contact record.

Following the instructions at [this site](http://blog.force365.com/2014/08/13/salesforce-live-agent/) I have a simple web page set up (omitting irrelevant portions, IDs and URLs sanitized):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://XXXXXX.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/31.0/deployment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // What do I do with this variable?
  var externalId = ...;

  if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
  window._laq.push(function(){
    liveagent.showWhenOnline('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online'));
    liveagent.showWhenOffline('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline'));
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  liveagent.init('https://XXXXXX.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
</script>

<div><a id="liveagent_button_online" href="javascript://Chat" style="display: none;"
    onclick="liveagent.startChat('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')">Chat is Online, click here to initiate a chat.</a></div>
<div id="liveagent_button_offline" style="display: none;">Chat is currently offline.</div>
```

This works: it brings up a chat window and it connects correctly. However, I need to pass the `externalId` variable into LiveAgent somewhere: this functionality is not covered by any documentation or tutorial that I can find.

How do I pass the external ID through the JavaScript API? If there is a way in Apex to have Salesforce automatically pull up the Contact based on a field name/value as a side effect that would be a nice bonus, but technically beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: There are different ways of doing that, are you using a pre-chat form ?

Comment: @PepeFloyd as of right now, the requirement is a simple chat link although that could change in the future. In the context of this question, let's say we are _not_ using a pre-chat form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a pre-chat form, you need to use the Deployment API.  See the example provided in the section called "**Deployment API Code Sample**" in the [Live Agent Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/index.htm), see the usage of the addCustomDetail method, you can use it to pass information to the chat or to search/create records based on custom information.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // An auto query that searches contacts whose email field matches "john@acme.com"
  liveagent.addCustomDetail('Contact E-mail', 'john@acme.com');
  liveagent.findOrCreate('Contact').map('Email','Contact E-mail',true,false,false);  
  // A fast-fill to populate a contact’s name with "John Doe"
  liveagent.addCustomDetail('Contact Name', 'John Doe');
  liveagent.findOrCreate('Contact').map('FirstName','Contact Name',false,false,false);
  // Saves the custom detail to a custom field on LiveChatTranscript at the end of a chat
  liveagent.addCustomDetail('Company', 'Acme').saveToTranscript('Company__c');
  // Overrides the display name of the visitor in the agent console when engaged in a chat
  liveagent.setName('John Doe');

  liveagent.init('https://d.la1s1.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572D0000000002R',
'00DD0000000JXbY');
</script>
```